# ¿Cómo puedo distinguir la conjunción «siempre que» (temporal) de «siempre que» (condicional)?

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis, conjunciones

No logro distinguir si la frase en negrita es una oración temporal o condicional:

> Estaba convencido de que una mujer que se acuesta con un hombre una
>   vez seguirá acostándose con él cada vez que él lo quiera, **siempre
>   que sepa enternecerla cada vez**.

Se usa el subjuntivo (con referencia de futuro) por eso creo que podría ser temporal pero no estoy completamente segura.

Answer (score 5):

Si está en indicativo, es temporal.

Si está en subjuntivo, no hay regla fija, depende del caso.

Aquí parece que saber enternecerla es una condición para que ella se acueste cada vez que él lo quiera (podríamos cambiar la oración a *“...seguirá acostándose con él cada vez que él lo quiera, **si sabe enternecerla cada vez**”*), y no algo que pasa siempre que él la enternece. Algunos días la enternecerá pero no querrá acostarse con ella, pero si quiere acostarse, tiene que enternecerla.

Una herramienta para saber si es temporal o condicional puede ser cambiar la oración para usar una construcción decididamente condicional o temporal y ver si tiene sentido, como hice más arriba.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando se tienen dudas, lo mejor es tratar de sustituir la expresión que te causa conflicto por otra que no te lo cause y que no modifique el sentido de la frase.

En el ejemplo, prueba a sustituir "siempre que" por "a condición de que". Verás que el sentido no cambia y seguro que ahora tienes más claro de qué tipo es la oración.

Si la frase fuera un complemento temporal, en todo caso, el verbo estaría en indicativo. Ejemplos:

> *Siempre que amanece me despierto automáticamente.* (=cuando amanece)
>
> *Siempre que viene el cartero tengo que amarrar al perro.* (=cuando viene)

Comment: Ya me ha vuelto a pasar lo de que alguien responde mientras escribo mi respuesta con la aplicación móvil... Como no me avisa...

Comment: muchas gracias a los dos! realmente aprecio!!!